# Error estimation of a simple case of the Newton-Raphson method

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Suppose we want to calculate the square root of some positive real number $k>0$. Using the Newton-Raphson method, we know that the recursive sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies: $$a_1=1\ \ \ ,\ \ \  a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+k}{2a_n}$$ will converge to $\sqrt{k}$ as desired.

My question is, given some $\varepsilon>0$, can we find an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ that for sure satisfies the inequality: $|a_m-\sqrt{k}|<\varepsilon$ ? (without knowing the value of $\sqrt{k}$ that we seek).

I know that in the general case there is **no** such nice estimation for the Newton-Raphson method, though I wonder, maybe there is one for that very simple case?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the value of k, how will you evaluate |am−√k| ?

Comment: See, for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455260/prove-fixed-point-iteration-of-gx-frac12x-fraca2x-converges-to, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941924/square-root-trick

Comment: @abstractnature Of course I could not evaluate that, but maybe just find an m for which a_m is at most epsilon away from the square root.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Not quite what I was asking about, though it seems relevant anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Your question as well as the question of constructing a very good initial guess is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2766631/307944

Comment: @CarlChristian Beautiful! thanks a lot.